# Python - Sorting lists which have string objects

Tags: list, python-3.x

I am trying to sort a list according to some values. I know how to sort according to integers and strings (alphabetically). Although, when it comes to objects that are made out of mathematical signs, I can't quite do it.

I have this list...

```
ls = ["Arsenal",10-5,10,"Chelsea",20-5,10]
```

I sort it with this:

```
newLs = sorted([ls[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(ls),3)],key=lambda x:(int(x[2]),int(x[1]))
```

I want `10-5` to be treated as `5` but later shown as `10-5` when being printed

Example of later print:

```
Arsenal   10-5   10
Chelsea   20-5   10
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error on the lambda part. You can't have the comma and the second part.

Comment: Remove `,int(x[1])` and it runs.

Comment: Also, your list `ls` declaration, put quotes around the elements that are numbers. `ls = ["Arsenal","10-5","10","Chelsea","20-5","10"`

Comment: it works, but I want to sort first by x[2] and then x[1]. Two conditions. Problem is the format of x[1] (being a-b instead of just an integer). I want to be able to add up the numbers. like 10-5=5 so 5 is less than 20-5=15. do you understand?

Comment: in my program everything is being treated as strings unless I tell them to be integers. Maybe I wasn't clear in my question with every quotation and sign

Comment: Try looking here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/#Key_Functions

Comment: Note that it IS treating them as numbers though. It is for me anyway. Maybe it's something to do with how your program implicitly uses numbers as strings? My problem is that your `key=...` is throwing errors.

Comment: See here: http://ideone.com/Jcu5b0

Comment: If you take away the int from int(x[1]), it will work. The problem is though that it wont give the correct answers to the 10-5 and 20-5.

Comment: I have been looking at the documentation and stuff, but there isn't anything even Close to that. Not sure what to do

Comment: Let me know if my solution below works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

Use `eval(x[2])` and so on. Also, parentheses are needed around it (makes it a tuple): `(eval(x[2]),eval(x[1]))`

```
ls = ["Arsenal","10-5","10","Chelsea","20-5","0+25"]

newLs = sorted([ls[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(ls),3)],key= lambda x: (eval(x[2]),eval(x[1])))

print(newLs)
```

Run it here: http://ideone.com/Jcu5b0

Comment: The `eval` function interprets an expression from a string, rather than attempting to parse the expression as an integer, which was causing an error.

Comment: Man I would upvote your answer 1000000000 times. You just made my day! That truly is genius! Thank you very much for this answer!

Comment: I'm glad I found it! I only found what the error was because I was trying to use repl.it (which uses Python 2.7), and it gave a more verbose error. Ideone just said "Runtime error"